# ESP32-mini-1 module not sending serial ACK for programming

Tags: c, esp32

I'm currently running ESP-IDF through VScode and have been using DEV kits for testing code. I've moved to a module as I've got a PCB made with it on to add in some peripherals etc.

Problem I've got is that when I try to program my new board through Tx/Rx/GND I cannot get an ACK back from my board to start the download of code. My ENable pin reads 3.1V and my VCC 3.3V, so I know the chip should be active. I've made sure my crystal is as close to the module as possible also.

Anyone got experience with the ESP-Prog tool for programming?

What I've checked so far is the following

- all the pins in the correct order like TX/RX maybe being swapped around - found no issue so left pin assignment as not the issue.
- Voltages are what they should be
- Made sure the schematic is correct
- all connected peripherals are Outputs on IO pins so shouldn't be receiving any issues on that front